# copy.copy vs copy.deepcopy performance on tuples

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

```
%python -m timeit -s "import copy" "x = (1, 2, 3)" "copy.deepcopy(x)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 usec per loop

%python -m timeit -s "import copy" "x = (1, 2, 3)" "copy.copy(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.609 usec per loop
```

Why is `deepcopy` 15 times slower than `copy`?

Each function has to iterate through the elements of the tuple. During that iteration, `copy` creates another reference to each element; `deepcopy` deepcopies each element.

But each element is an `int`, and deepcopying an `int` simply creates another reference to it. In other words, the two functions seem to perform precisely the same steps, the same number of times.

Here's the verification that no new instances are created in the process:

```
ActivePython 3.2.1.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 18 2011, 14:31:09) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = (1,2,3)
>>> import copy
>>> y = copy.copy(x)
>>> z = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> x is y
True
>>> x is z
True
>>> x[1] is z[1]
True
```

Comment: Not a real answer, but a suspicion: `deepcopy` needs to keep track which elements it has already copied to allow for cyclic references, which might add some overhead, especially in such simple cases.

Comment: If you can roll your own copy of "deepcopy" it may be worth it. I was profiling some evolutionary algorithm code and it was spending a lot of time in deepcopy. I was able to determine the constraints needed for the algorithm and write my own limited version of deepcopy which lead to a substantial speed-up. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, but they can contain mutable elements:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, [])
>>> a[2].append(1000)
>>> a
(1, 2, [1000])
```

Note that the tuple doesn't change: it's the list the one that does; the tuple still contains the exact same list.

`deepcopy` should recurse copying those mutable elements. `copy` just copies the references to them.

```
>>> from copy import copy, deepcopy

>>> a = (1, 2, [])
>>> c = copy(a)
>>> d = deepcopy(a)

>>> a[2].append(1000)

>>> c
(1, 2, [1000])
>>> d
(1, 2, [])
```

Comment: Yes, but both `copy` and `deepcopy` need to iterate through the elements of the tuple. As they do, `copy` creates another reference to each `int`, while `deepcopy` copies the `int` instance. But copying the `int` instance simply returns another reference to the same instance. Seems like the two functions should do precisely the same steps. I don't see how this results in 15x performance hit.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to iterate over the tuple for shallow copying. Without knowing that much about Python internals, I'd guess that a memcpy call should suffice.

Comment: You're right, no need to iterate for `copy`. Python doesn't even need `memcpy`: it can just return another reference to the original tuple! Of course, that's not going to work for `deepcopy`.